# Create a struct from a byte array

Tags: json, go, go-interface

I use the [`json.Marshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) interface to accept a `map[string]interface{}` and convert it to a `[]byte` (is this a byte array?)

```
data, _ := json.Marshal(value)
log.Printf("%s\n", data)
```

I get this output

```
{"email_address":"joe@me.com","street_address":"123 Anywhere Anytown","name":"joe","output":"Hello World","status":1}
```

The underlying bytes pertain to the struct of the below declaration

```
type Person struct {
    Name           string  `json:"name"`
    StreetAddress  string  `json:"street_address"`
    Output         string  `json:"output"`
    Status         float64 `json:"status"`
    EmailAddress   string  `json:"email_address",omitempty"`
}
```

I'd like to take `data` and generate a variable of type `Person struct`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `json.Unmarshal`:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    Name          string  `json:"name"`
    StreetAddress string  `json:"street_address"`
    Output        string  `json:"output"`
    Status        float64 `json:"status"`
    EmailAddress  string  `json:"email_address",omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    data := []byte(`{"email_address":"joe@me.com","street_address":"123 Anywhere Anytown","name":"joe","output":"Hello World","status":1}`)
    var p Person
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &p); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", p)
}
```

Output:

```
main.Person{Name:"joe", StreetAddress:"123 Anywhere Anytown", Output:"Hello World", Status:1, EmailAddress:"joe@me.com"}
```

Comment: Awesome! This works! Although I have two follow up questions: This seems a bit roundabout - We first marshal and then unmarshal - is that normal? Is there a way to directly obtain Person struct from map[string]interface{} ? . My second question: lets say email_address field did not exist in data(since its an omitempty field). Do i need to do anything special with the Unmarshal call? Or the above would still work?

Comment: @nthacker, it is somewhat roundabout, but for all I know, there isn't a simple way to convert a map directly into a struct. The real question, however, is where are you getting that map from in the first place? Why is the thing that's producing it not simply giving you a struct? Maybe you could refactor your code so that you don't need a map at all. As for your second question... is there something that prevents your from trying it out yourself?

Comment: you are right on both counts! Thanks I'll look into both of those!

Comment: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema or https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure